# Windows form scaling doesn't work on other pc

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scaling

I have developed an windows form application. I've used anchor to auto scale my application so it looks well ordered while resizing or maximizing.

Everything's okay on my pc, but when I tried to test my application on another pc, the objects in my application does not auto scale to the size of the application and I don't know why. There isn't any error and the program works fine.

Both pcs are running windows 7.

can someone explain what is wrong with my application? thank you!

Comment: you definitely anchored everything correctly yeah?

Comment: Is the screen resolution the same on both PCs?.  That has caused many problems for me.

Comment: @werdna yes it works fine on my pc.

Comment: @HaimKatz no the screen resolution is different.
all the objects remain where they are when I tried it on another pc

Comment: What scaling mode you are using?

Comment: @arvo err does using anchor consider as a scaling mode?

Comment: I can't help you much.  I haven't done this for a while, but I remember when I did I made all the clients revert to the same screen resolution otherwise I never could get it to work.  (Only applicable for small numbers of clients).

Comment: what happens if you use the same monitor on the computer that isn't working? just to confirm its not a driver or something related.

Comment: @HaimKatz I see, I'll take note of it and try to see if there's any problem regarding the resolution. thanks anyways! :)

Comment: @Werdna I tried it and it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you provide some screen shots?  Anchor is not a scaling mode, it just positions the controls relative to a corner of the form when the the form is resized.  The controls stay the same size.